# Unable to access "child" page of route using ngRoute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I can't seem to make my routing (`ngRoute`) to pick up on a child page (`/login/create`). Whenever I attempt to access that route I get pushed back to the beginning (`"/"`):

```
(function () {
    angular.module('kioskApp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                controller: "homeController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "../../app/home/home.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/login", {
                controller: "loginController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "../../app/login/login.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/login/create", { // <--- can't go there?
                controller: "createUserController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "../../app/login/create.html"
            });


            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
        });

})();
```

I'm fully able to go to `/login`, but for some reason I can't get to `/login/create` using my anchor that lives in `/login.html`:

```
<a href="#!/login/create/" class="btn btn-danger" 
        ng-show="!vm.listIsSet" style="float:right;">Create New</a>
```

[image]

Comment: try `href="#/login/create/"`

Comment: @sachilaranawaka that gets me to the right `.html` file. However it really messes up my URL. Angular 1.6 uses the '!' as an escape character for the hashbang, doesn't it?

Comment: its depend on the ngroute version